# Download the PS4 game only once

Tags: ps4

We have two PS4s in the house and we basically download and play the same games. Is there a way that one can download the game and then have the game transferred via the local network to the other PS4? The reason I'm asking is because our internet is not the fastest, especially when something has to be downloaded two times.

Answer (score 1):

If you used and extended storage device and downloaded the game to that on PS4 1 and then plugged it into PS4 2 and installed it on to that system it might work. You might still have to wait for the game to copy.

EDIT: If you do this make sure to go into sound and devices and hit stop using extended storage. If you don't do this the data could corrupt.

Comment: While good in theory, this won't work. If they went this route, they would run into licensing issues and would need to sign into the original owner of the game in order to play it. See [here](https://www.gamesradar.com/ps4-external-hard-drive-transfer-games/)

Comment: It should work exactly the same as if you had downloaded it to two consoles.  You can run the game on any console that either has the owning account as primary or is signed in to the owning account.   Using this method, it is possible to play the game on two different consoles at the same time.